How do you run ssh /bin/bash << EOF commands in groovy?
I entered the following code into my bash shell:
export letters="a b c"
ssh centos@x.x.x.x /bin/bash << EOF
echo $letters
for letter in ${letters}; do
    echo "hello \$letter"
done
EOF

And got the expected output
a b c
hello a
hello b
hello c

However, when I wrote a groovy script to do the same:
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('print letters') {
            steps {
                script {
                env.letters="a b c"
                sh'''
                    ssh centos@x.x.x.x /bin/bash << EOF
                    echo $letters
                    for letter in ${letters}; do
                        echo "hello \$letter"
                    done
EOF
'''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I get
a b c
hello 
hello 
hello 

So all of the variables being set in the ssh shell are being ignored.

That's missing the closing ''' so won't run. What's your actual code and output (as I assume what you posted was just an approximate guess)

@tim_yates Sorry, the code I have does run but i modified it to make this question shorter. I've added the missing apostrophes

Is there a reason to do this with shell instead of pipeline or Groovy?

@MatthewSchuchard the node I'm sshing into isn't an agent

Groovy string syntax swallowed one level of \ escaping. You would need to escape \ to pass it to shell.
                        echo "hello \\$letter"

